# What is the shortcut to open a file within your solution in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

What is the shortcut to open a file within your solution in Visual Studio 2008 (+ Resharper)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (ReSharper, Goto, type) will open a class file for you.

Looks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opens files.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your keymap, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will open any file in the solution, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will open any type.

Answer (score 2):

If the standard toolbar is visible the following will open any file in the solution (resharper is not necessary).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> places you in the Find textbox.  `>of f` will provide a dropdown with all files that start with `f` with path information after the filename to distinguish name collisions. Complete the filename, or arrow down to the correct one and hit enter to open it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the key mapping that you have set. 
With default keymapping: Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a type and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a file.
With IntelliJ like mapping : Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open a type and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open a file.

Visit the following links for all your key mapping.

ReSharper 4 Default Keymap: Visual Studio scheme
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper40DefaultKeymap.pdf

ReSharper 4 Default Keymap: ReSharper 2.x / IDEA scheme
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper40DefaultKeymap2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I attended a presentation recently where [Kirk Jackson](http://pageofwords.com/blog/default.aspx) showed how to add aliases to the command window in Visual Studio. Bear with me, it gets better.
So it went like this:

1. Open Command Window and type

   > alias fo File.FileOpen
2. Now in your editor window hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to put the focus into the Find box on the toolbar
3. If you use the prefix `>` this is command window (sneaky huh?) so type:

   > fo

and intellisense kicks in and shows you the names of the folders and files in the solution.

The alias is persistent between Visual Studio sessions.

Not exactly a keyboard shortcut but using this technique you can access any command in Visual Studio from the keyboard.

You should also check out Kirk's list of essential [VS tips and tricks](http://pageofwords.com/blog/2008/09/09/VisualStudioTipsNTricksDEV313.aspx)